# Linux 'socketcall' system call implementation

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

In linux all socket related system calls are gated  throw one system call named [socketcall](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.11.1/net/socket.c#L2453).Its handler is found in `/net/socket.c`. As one can expect there are a copy_from_user for the arguments and then a switch for all socket functions.

I expected to see in each case a call for a ordinary function , but it seems that there are callings to another system calls. For example the case for 'socket' :

```
case SYS_SOCKET:
    err = sys_socket(a0, a1, a[2]);
    break;
```

sys_socket is also defined in `/net/socket.c` as :

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(socket, int, family, int, type, int, protocol)
```

My question is why its defined like this. I guess its for backward compatibility, or I have a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man 2 socketcall` says that

> NOTES
> On a few architectures, for example ia64, there is no socketcall() system call; instead socket(2), accept(2), bind(2), and so on really
> are implemented as separate system calls

So, in the case of x86, the `socketcall` dispatcher is only for `x86_32`, while `x86_64` uses separate system calls for each socket API.